# CSS - <a> Elements stacking over each other after resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have buttons with these properties:

```
background: #c6cdf2;
border: 1px solid #8896e4;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 6px 10px 3px 10px;
```

Once the page resizes they don't seem to care about the padding and start stacking in each other.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to automaticaly calculate the proper margin between the borders? I don't want to set a fixed amount of margin to encounter this.

Comment: Flex property support only IE10 and IE11 so better use of media queries.see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flexbox. no need for media queries or extra code. simplify it.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a {
  background: #c6cdf2;
  border: 1px solid #8896e4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 10px 3px;
  margin: 10px /* whatever you want here */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">long long long text</a>
  <a href="#">long long text demo</a>
  <a href="#">short text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex property support only IE10 and IE11.

Answer (score 1):

**Flex property dont support IE9,IE8 so better use of media queries.**

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 380px) {

          .yourSelector {

            display: block;
            width: 100%;

          }
    }
```

**And insert `margin:0.5%` AND `box-sizing: border-box`** .

**Full Code :**

```css
.b {

    background: #c6cdf2;
    border: 1px solid #8896e4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 10px 3px 10px;
    margin: 0.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 380px) {

        .b {
            
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
          }

}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="b">Button1 </button>
<a href="#" class="b">Button2 </button>
<a href="#" class="b">Button3 </button>
<a href="#" class="b">Button4 </button>
<a href="#" class="b">Button5 </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding two more style properties:

`float: left;`
`clear: both;`

Hope that would help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your elements are inline(display:inline) so you can make paddings with line-height property, or make them block, or inline-block to use paddings